# Get row data in Ext JS 3.0 Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a grid, which I want to add a button at the top to get the data from a specific column for each row selected in the grid.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add something like this to the button's click event:

```
rowsSelected = myGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelections();
for(...){
    aRecord = rowsSelected[i];
    filedValue = aRecord.get('fieldName');
}
```